# Cognos Query Calculation

Tags: cognos

I want to calculate outage percent and here is my query :

```
[Time Diff]*100/[Time Total]
```

This is query calculation. But here is the deal this calculation end up with zero. **Time Diff** is smaller than **Time Total**. Layout calculation gives right result. It should be like this after calculation : **0.1879458**. But query calculation gives **zero**.

What should I do ? What is the deal ?

Comment: Have you tried to start the expression with a float constant like this: `100.0*[Time Diff] / [Time Total]`?

Comment: To clarify @MarcusRickert 's comment, assuming `[TIME DIFF]` and `[TIME Total]` are both integers, you can force an implicit cast by multiplying one of them by a decimal.  Or you can actively cast one of them to a decimal.